Opening multiple files leads to the termination of file managers. Why?
Opening multiple files (more that 16) leads to the termination of file managers (tested on nemo & nautilus in ubuntu 22.04 & 24.04).
When I try to open more than 16 songs in a music player via file manager, it exits without an error code. This has been tested with two file managers (Nemo and Nautilus) and several music players in Ubuntu (versions 22.04 and 24.04). Why is this happening? Is it a bug?
UPD:
a@a:~$ nemo

** (nemo:5004): WARNING **: 11:37:16.020: Current gtk theme is not known to have nemo support (Yaru-remix) - checking...
Ended
a@a:~$

The warning is shown at startup and is not related to the problem.

Try launching the file manager from a terminal (open a terminal and run nautilus) and then use that one to do what you do. When it fails, there should be an error message printed in the terminal, please come and include that in your question.

It's probably a crash. Report this to Ubuntu Bugs

The joke is that there is no error. Both file managers terminated in the standard way.

The best way to confirm whether some unexpected/undocumented behaviour is a bug is to file a bug report. If it is expected, the devs will say as much, and if it is a bug, then they automatically become aware of it as well
